# Efficiently generate a flexible class with property decorators

Tags: typescript, class-validator

Lately I got mixed up in the situation where I had to copy and paste a lot of my code. This bothered me. This occurred to me while I was working with so called Data Transfer Objects (DTO's) or in this case it's maybe more some kind of validation object.

To simplify the question I will use the well-known `User` class as the domain entity to implement DTO's for.

Let's consider the following interface for the `User` object:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

With that also come some requirements:

- When creating a new user only the `name` prop is required.
- When editing an existing user all props should be optional.
- The user can be retrieved by `name`.
- The `name` prop should be only in alpha characters.
- The `age` prop should be a positive integer.
- *... in reality there are many more ...*

When using [`class-validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator), you should use decorators to add validation to an object. Thus an `User` object what should be used to validate requests when creating an user, could look like this:

```
class CreateUser implements User {
  @IsAlpha()
  name: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsPositive()
  @IsInt()
  age?: number;
}
```

---

Great that's one done for creating users, now one for editing we basically need to partially extend the `CreateUser` class, also the `name` property should be optional and get the `@IsOptional()` decorator.

Unfortunately extending the `CreateUser` class will cause a lot of inconveniences. Most importantly the decorators from the extended class will be lost if we try to re-declare an extended property. One possible solution for this use case would be to use [`decorate-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decorate-all).

```
@DecorateAll(IsOptional, { deep: true });
class EditUser extends CreateUser implements Partial<User> {};
```

Unfortunately this doesn't make the `name` property optional, but it gets the validation part of the job done. This basically only requires you to cast the DTO instance to the interface, I think that's something what you always should do so not a big deal.

---

Now last but not least we should write a DTO what should be used for retrieving a user by `name`. Thus the DTO should basically be an extension of the `CreateUser` class, but while extending it should only pick the `name` property. I don't know how you can "pick" with classes, so this one I would just copy and paste...

```
class GetUserByName implements Pick<User, 'code'> {
  @IsAlpha()
  name: string;
}
```

---

Not to difficult right? But as you can imagine this gets pretty messy, difficult to maintain and easy to make mistakes with. Then again this is only based on a few requirements while in reality it are way more. Anyway I hope you get my point by now.

To get to my question, is there a more efficient way to do this? Perhaps is there a way to generate classes with decorators?

It would be great to be able to do something like this:

```
interface DecoratedClassConfig<T> {
  [prop: keyof T]: PropertyDecorator[];
}

const decoratedUserConfig: DecoratedClassConfig<User> = {
  name: [IsAlpha],
  age: [IsOptional, IsPositive, IsInt],
};

class BaseUser implements User {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
}

class CreateUser extends DecorateClass(BaseUser, decoratedUserConfig) {}

const decoratedEditUserConfig = {
  ...decoratedUserConfig,
  user: [...decoratedUserConfig.user, IsOptional]
};
// Or just decorate the class with: @DecorateAll(IsOptional, { deep: true });
class EditUser extends DecorateClass(BaseUser, decoratedEditUserConfig) {}

const decoratedGetByUserNameConfig = {
  name: decoratedUserConfig.name,
};
class GetUserByName extends DecorateClass(BaseUser, decoratedGetByUserNameConfig) {}
```